# Codeigniter - Get other database information and place into Session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm new to CodeIgniter and I made a Login System where in I have a session. Here, I can get the username of the account by using POST and placing it in the session array. However, I also want to get its other data, such as its first name, last name, etc. from the database and place it into the session also. What is the proper syntax in order for me to achieve it?

**Controller:**

```
function validate_login()
{
    $this->load->model('model_accounts');
    $valid = $this->model_accounts->validate();
    $isAdmin = $this->model_accounts->check_role();
    $isActive = $this->model_accounts->check_active();

    if($valid && $isAdmin && $isActive) // Active Admin
    {
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'), 
            'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect('admin_ticketing');
    }
    else if(($valid && $isActive) && $isAdmin == false)  // Active User
    {
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password'),   
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect('user_home');
    }
    else if(($valid && $isAdmin) && $isActive == false)  //Deactivated Admin
    {
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect('login/admindeact');
    }
    else if($valid && ($isActive && $isAdmin) == false) //Deactivated User
    {
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect('login/userdeact');
    }
    else if($valid == false) //Invalid Account
    {
        $data['main_content'] = 'view_login';
        $data['message'] = "The username and password you entered did not match our records. Please double-check and try again. ";
        $this->load->view('includes/login_template', $data);
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
function validate() 
{
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password'));
    $query = $this->db->get('accounts');

    if($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        return true;    
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

function check_role() 
{
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password'));
    $this->db->where('role', 1);
    $query = $this->db->get('accounts');

    if($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {

        return true;    
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}

function check_active() 
{
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password'));
    $this->db->where('isActive', 1);
    $query = $this->db->get('accounts');

    if($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        return true;    
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create an array in session and store all datas you need like this $this->session->set_userdata('sessionarr',$resultset);

Comment: I have already created this array `$data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );` But I want to take for example the firstname of the one with the username above from the database. I want to know how to do it

Comment: take up the users data from the database using provided username and password, and store it again like you said... `eg: if($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        return $query->result;    //it contains all userdata
    }`

Comment: @coderszx check following answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done your page redirection from controller and set session on model as following:

Controller:

```
function validate_login()
{
    $this->load->model('model_accounts');
    $valid = $this->model_accounts->validate();
    $isAdmin = $this->model_accounts->check_role();
    $isActive = $this->model_accounts->check_active();

    if($valid && $isAdmin && $isActive) // Active Admin
    {
        redirect('admin_ticketing');
    }
    else if(($valid && $isActive) && $isAdmin == false)  // Active User
    {

        redirect('user_home');
    }
    else if(($valid && $isAdmin) && $isActive == false)  //Deactivated Admin
    {

        redirect('login/admindeact');
    }
    else if($valid && ($isActive && $isAdmin) == false) //Deactivated User
    {

        redirect('login/userdeact');
    }
    else if($valid == false) //Invalid Account
    {
        $data['main_content'] = 'view_login';
        $data['message'] = "The username and password you entered did not match our records. Please double-check and try again. ";
        $this->load->view('includes/login_template', $data);
    }
}
```

And

Model:

```
function validate() 
{
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password'));
    $query = $this->db->get('accounts');
    $result = $query->row();

    if($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
     $data = array(
            'username' => $result->username, 
            'password' => $result->password,
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        return true;    
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

function check_role() 
{
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password'));
    $this->db->where('role', 1);
    $query = $this->db->get('accounts');
    $result = $query->row();

    if($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
         $data = array(
            'username' => $result->username, 
            'password' => $result->password,
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        return true;    
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}

function check_active() 
{
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password'));
    $this->db->where('isActive', 1);
    $query = $this->db->get('accounts');
    $result = $query->row();

    if($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        $data = array(
            'username' => $result->username, 
            'password' => $result->password,
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        return true;    
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! I get an error, which is:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::num_rows()

and it points here: 
` if($query->num_rows() == 1)`

Comment: don't forget to load `session()` library.